# How to deal with a lot of plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a for loop which produces  60 plots. I would like to save all this plots in only one file. 
If I set `par(mfrow=c(10,6))` it says : `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

What can I do?

My code is as follows:

```
pdf(file="figure.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(10,6))
for(i in 1:60){
  x=rnorm(100)
  y=rnorm(100)
  plot(x,y)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: how should this look like? If you plot 60 plots in one graphic device / graphic output, this would not be readable anymore?

Comment: I need a table of plots.  I do not know if would be readable . At least a can plot 2 documents of 30 plot . But I need something like that.

Comment: Sorry @gung  yes i think you can migrate the post

Comment: What you appear to be doing in your original code is squeezing 60 sub-figures into a single figure (!). This is poor design at best. The answer from @gung will give you sixty figures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your default plot, as stated in the loop, does not use the space very effectively. If you look at just a single plot, you can see it has large margins, both between axis and edge and plot area and axis text. Effectively, there is a lot of space-hogging.

Secondly, the default pdf-function creates small pages, 7 by 7 inches. That is not a large sheet to plot on.

Trying to plot a 10 x 6 or 12 x 5 on 7 by 7 inches is therefore trying to squeeze in a lot of whitespace on very little space.

For it to succeed, you must look into the margin-options of `par` which is `mar`, `mai`, `oma` and `omi`, and probably some more. Consult the documentation with the command

```
?par
```

In addition to this, you could consider not displaying axis-text, tick-marks, tick-labels and titles for every one of the 60 sub-plots, as this too will save you space.

But somebody has already gone through some of this trouble for you. Look into the [`lattice`](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html)-package or [`ggplot2`](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html), which has some excellent methods for making table-like subplots.

But there is another pressing issue: What are you trying to display with 60 subplots?

---

**Update**

Seeing what you are trying to do, here is a small example of faceting in `ggplot2`. It uses the Tufte-theme from jrnold's [ggthemes](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes), which is copied into here and then modified slightly in the line after the function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#### Setup the `theme` for the plot, i.e. the appearance of background, lines, margins, etc. of the plot.
##   This function returns a theme-object, which ggplot2 uses to control the appearance.
theme_tufte <- function(ticks=TRUE, base_family="serif", base_size=11) {
  ret <- theme_bw(base_family=base_family, base_size=base_size) +
    theme(
      legend.background = element_blank(),
      legend.key        = element_blank(),
      panel.background  = element_blank(),
      panel.border      = element_blank(),
      strip.background  = element_blank(),
      plot.background   = element_blank(),
      axis.line         = element_blank(),
      panel.grid = element_blank())
  if (!ticks) {
    ret <- ret + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
  }
  ret
}

## Here I modify the theme returned from the function,
theme <- theme_tufte() + theme(panel.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), 'lines'),     panel.border=element_rect(colour='grey', fill=NA))
## and instruct ggplot2 to use this theme as default.
theme_set(theme)

#### Some data generation.
size = 60*30
data <- data.frame(x=runif(size), y=rexp(size)+rnorm(size), mdl=sample(60,size, replace=TRUE))

#### Main plotting routine.
ggplot(data, aes(x,y, group=mdl)) ## base state of the plot to be used on all "layers", i.e. which data to use and which mappings to use (x should use x-variable, y should use the y-variable
  + geom_point()                  ## a layer that renders data as points, creates the scatterplot
  + stat_quantile(formula=y~x)    ## another layer that adds some statistics, in this case the 25%, 50% and 75% quantile lines.
  + facet_wrap(~ mdl, ncol=6)     ## Without this, all the groups would be displayed in one large plot; this breaks it up according to the `mdl`-variable.
```

[image: Faceting with <code>ggplot2</code>.]

The usual challenge in using `ggplot2` is restructuring all your data into data.frames. For this task, the `reshape2` and `plyr`-packages might be of good use.
For you, I would imagine that your function that creates the subplot both calculates the estimation *and* creates the plot. This means that you have to split the function into calculating the estimation, returning it to a `data.frame`, which you then can collate and pass to `ggplot`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a family of 60 models and I have to compare an estimation method on each one of this models. The only way to compare the results is the graphical one. In the end I have to report this graphics in a thesis.

Comment: This looks to be the easiest way. Can you pleas explain it a little better?  Suppose to have only two plot : a=rnorm(10)
b=a*a
c=rnorm(20)
d=c            What I have to do if I want the plot (a,b) and (d,c)?

Comment: The faceting in `ggplot2` are intended for when the respective axes are identical on all subplots. What you are asking is not appropriate with the faceting as you want to compare 2 x 2 variables, side by side. In this case, you should use `par(mfcol)` options or the `layout` function.

Comment: ok thanks I got this . Last question : How is possible to have in the same plot lines and hist?

Comment: Please ask this in a new question; then you can give some more details, e.g. if it is R's native `plot` or `ggplot`, a facsimile of the data, code, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Output the plots to a pdf:

```
X = matrix(rnorm(60*100), ncol=60)
Y = matrix(rnorm(60*100), ncol=60)

pdf(file="fileName.pdf")
  for(j in 1:60){
    plot(X[,j], Y[,j])
  }
dev.off()
```

Comment: You can also, within this loop, output multiple plots per page using par(4,4) or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but why should it work? I am already using the pdf format. Are you talking about  par(mfrow=c(2,2))?

Answer (score 3):

For placing many plots on a page or document (and I have created images with literally thousands of plots in them), it is convenient to separate the work between `R`--which creates the plots *individually*--and other software which is better suited for arranging arrays of things.  If this reminds you of spreadsheets or word processing tables, then we are thinking alike.

[image: Figure]

*This page, which is a screenshot from a PDF file, contains over 200 statistical graphics. Although it has been greatly reduced (to 40% nominal size) in order to obscure proprietary data, the original has all the detail of the original `R` graphics and can be zoomed to 1600% without problem.*

Two mechanisms have worked reasonably well.  For up to several hundred plots, a little macro to import and re-sequence a set of bitmapped image files (.emf or .wmf) into a Word document does fine.  For better control, I turn to a comparable Excel macro.  It is driven by a sheet that is empty of everything except a row with column headers and a column with row headers.  (You can see them at the left and top of the figure.)  The macro deletes everything else on that sheet (except for formatting), then munges each possible combination of row and column header into a file name and if it finds that file, it imports it into the corresponding cell.  The whole operation takes just a few seconds for several thousand images.

Obviously this communication mechanism between `R` and the other software is primitive, consisting of a collection of image files having a standard naming convention.  But the code needed to implement it all is brief (albeit customized to each situation) and it works reliably.  For example, if you encapsulate the plotting code within a function, then it will be called within a loop to create many similar plots.  At the end of that function add a few lines to save the plot to a file, something like this:

```r
path <- "W: <whatever>/"                # Folder for the output files
ext <- "wmf" # or "emf" or "png" or ... # Format (and extension) of the output
...
if (save) {
  outfile <- paste(path, paste(munge(well), munge(parm), sep="_"), sep="/")
  outfile <- paste(outfile, ext, sep=".")
  savePlot(filename=outfile, type=ext)
}
```

In this case each plot is identified by two loop variables, `well` and `parm`, both of which are strings (they correspond to the column and row headers).  The function for creating acceptable filenames merely strips out punctuation, replacing it by an anodyne placeholder:

```
munge <- function(s) gsub("[[:punct:]]", "_", s)
```

Once those images have been imported into Word, Excel, or wherever you like, it's fairly easy to reorganize them, place other material around them, etc., and then print the result in PDF format.

---

There is an art to creating these very large "small multiples" (in Tufte's terminology). To the extent possible, it helps to follow Tufte's principle of increasing the data:ink ratio *by erasing inessential material*.  That makes graphical patterns clear even when the tableau has been greatly reduced in size in order to comprehend all its rows and columns at once.  Although the preceding figure is a poor example--the individual plots had to have axes, gridlines, labels, and so on so that they can be read in detail when zoomed--the power of this method to *reveal patterns* is clear even at this scale.  It is crucial to make the plots comparable to one another.  In this example, which consists of time series, every plot has the same range on the x-axis; within each row (which corresponds to a different type of observation), the ranges on the y-axes are the same; and all color schemes and methods of symbolization are the same throughout.

Comment: Glad you mentioned Tufte.
On a separate note, the same idea applies with LaTeX: Output each subplot as a pdf og ps-file and make a script that writes the LaTeX code for inserting all graphics into a table or subfigure.

Comment: @MrGumble It's nice to know that this can be done in LaTeX. What is especially nice about the Excel solution is its immediate interaction: you can reorder rows and columns, cut and paste among them, resize them (which causes the images in the cells to resize accordingly), format them (that's where the pink highlighting comes from in my figure), and more. I don't believe there is any such Wysiwyg capability for LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `knitr`. This didn't instantly convert over to base graphics (and I've got to run now), but using `ggplot` works easily.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE, fig.keep='high', fig.height=3, fig.width=4>>=
require(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:10) print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point())
@


\end{document}
```

The above code will produce a nice multi-page pdf with all the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple solution to this type of issue, I found that setting a large "Windows" device manages to make the window big enough for many uses.

```
windows(50,50)
par(mfrow=c(10,6))
for(i in 1:60){
  x=rnorm(100)
  y=rnorm(100)
  plot(x,y)
}
```

Or in my case,

```
windows(20,20)
plot(Plotting_I_Need_In_Rows_of_4, mfrow=c(4,4))
```