# Is there a R function to adjust layout under for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame and a code to plot all graphs that is a factor. But I need to adjust the layout. I need 2 rows and 1 column in a plot. But current code is only showing 1 column and 3 rows

```
 df
  a  b c  d
1 a dg 1 dg
2 b dg 2 dg
3 a dg 3 dg
4 d fd 4 fd

p <- list()
as <- names(Filter(is.factor, df))
for(i in 1:length(as))
{
p[[i]] <- 
print(ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x=as[i],fill=as[i]))+geom_bar(stat = 
"count"))
do.call(grid.arrange,p)
}
```

I need to adjust the layouts here. How can I?

Comment: Do you have a pressing need for working with `grid.arrange`? A few packages (e.g. cowplot, patchwork) are designed to make it easy to build layouts of lists of `ggplot` objects and are very flexible

Answer (score 1):

Is this the layout you are looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- read.table(text = "
a  b c  d
1 a dg 1 dg
2 b dg 2 dg
3 a dg 3 dg
4 d fd 4 fd
", header = T)

as <- names(Filter(is.factor, df))

p <- list()

for(i in 1:length(as))
{
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x=as[i],fill=as[i]))+geom_bar(stat = "count")
}

grid.arrange(grobs = p, ncol = 2, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 3)))
```

[image: Revised plot with grid.arrange]

**Edit**: grid.arrange includes layout based on comment with second row plot the full width.

Based on your comments regarding which plot to place in which location, you can specify your individual grobs specifically:

```
grid.arrange(grobs = c(p[3], p[1], p[2]), ncol = 2, ...
```

Or you can order your grobs with some logic before plotting.

Comment: A kind off, I need to third graph to get extended throughout the screen. Because my problem is, if the graph is long enough lets say the the third graph has many factors like dg, fd, sd,fg,ty,wq,uy,ui,er,df,hg. Plotting this in a small graph does not look nice. So Whenever the factors are more, the graph plot should expend so that it is clear. Hope you got my point. Its is also difficult to convey the message properly sorry for that

Comment: Perfect thanks. Just want to know. Since this is a loop, d graph is coming at the last so we can extend it. What if I need, b graph in place of d graph and d graph in place of b graph. I think it is not possible?

Comment: Sorry If I am confusing you

Comment: Hi Ben small clarification. In the last code of yours " grid.arrange(grobs = p, ncol = 2, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 3))) " Say we have 50 plots. I mean "p" has 50 plots. I tried with the code   " grid.arrange(grobs = p, ncol = 25, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1:25), c(26:50)))  " But I am getting error. May I know why?

Comment: Warning message:
In rbind(c(1, 25), c(26:50)) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)     This is the error message I am getting

Comment: is it not possible to get all 50 plots?

Comment: Also would you be interested in cowplot or patchwork?

Comment: also - your warning suggests you had `c(1, 25)` and not `c(1:25)` - was that intentional?

Comment: Yeah it should be 1:25. And yes P has 50 plots. Is it not possible to plot?

Comment: Actually we can plot but we need to enter manually. Even though we enter manually all the plots will be congested, Can we not make it scroll down kind of thing so that everything fits and is clear

Comment: Yes, you should be able to plot 50 plots. Besides `grid.arrange` you could use `marrangeGrob(p, nrow=10, ncol=5)` (if you want to still travel down this road - I just tried this out, it works). However you may need to consider how you want your spacing (you can specify `widths` and `heights` of your columns and rows). I think `cowplot` or `patchwork` might be worth considering. Is the goal screen output only? Or a file or something else? Other info on dealing with many plots in r can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698741/how-to-deal-with-a-lot-of-plots-in-r

Comment: I want to be helpful, but perhaps you might want to get other opinions managing a large number of plots on the screen; consider posting a separate SO question? And describe in detail what you ultimately want to have in the end (full screen of plots, pdf or png on single or multiple pages, etc.).

Comment: I just noticed another question you posted about this - looks like providing more details with code and examples, and maybe a picture of what your desired outcome would be might help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ben, I have pasted the image here https://imgur.com/tsX6MQZ  Hope this helps. If you look at the bottom, you can see there a scroll bar that we can move towards right. What I mean to say is the entire graph should get extended